# Is it possible to query the Blood Oxygen Saturation sensor from your own app on Apple Watch Series 6?

Tags: ios, healthkit, watchos

Good morning,

This may be a bit of a stupid question but I cannot find the answer anywhere!

For a project I am working on a requirement is to regularly check the user's blood oxygen levels. I understand that through HealthKit I can view stored SPO2 results, however I have not been able to find a way to initiate a Blood Oxygen Saturation test from my own application.

Is this even possible? If so, a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Edit for more detail: I've managed to get other health data to query regularly such as Heart Rate by using a workout and WatchKit Connection to send updates to the iOS device regularly. This method does not seem to be suitable for Blood Oxygen as there is no workout that tracks SPO2. Perhaps there is a way to add SPO2 tracking to a workout?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger an SpO2 measurement on the watch through API. You should file a feedback assistant request to Apple with your use case if you need this functionality.